# I get an arror for map function(posts.map is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux

I get this error, while I don't see any issue in that:

`posts.map is not a function`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const PostsList = () => {
  const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts)

  const renderedPosts = posts.map(post => (
    <article className="post-excerpt" key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p className="post-content">{post.content.substring(0, 100)}</p>
    </article>
  ))

  return (
    <section className="posts-list">
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      {renderedPosts}
    </section>
  )
}
```

This is my code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-darkness-6hi04d?file=/src/features/posts/PostsList.js

Comment: You should include the relevant code directly in your post, which includes the store configuration/initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in the file store.js

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: () => ({
    posts: postsReducer
  })
});
```

Modify this file as follows :

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes! exactly! thanks Soheil:)